# Windows pauses my process after a short time if memory consumption is high

Tags: c++, windows, memory, opencl

I am using a 3d-lattice to update two fields in time, using OpenCL kernels for the update rule, and a C++ host program, and run my program under Windows 64bit with 8GB RAM. The application is built using VS2017.

My problem is: No matter whether I use my graphics card or the CPU for the computation, the application is paused by Windows after a brief time (about 15min), and I have to press a key in the open console to wake it up, afer which it continues running, but stops outputting status information to the console (which it should do).

This happens only when I use a lot of memory, i.e. compute on a big lattice with at least 3GB of allocated memory, with less memory consumption the program runs just fine for as long as I need it to.

Of course, I would like to be able to run my simulations without having to watch my PC all the time.I already tried increasing the priority of the process, which did not help.

Is there a way to tell Windows to leave my processes running?

Comment: I have never heard of Windows pausing processes that use a lot of memory, nor of pressing a key in the console making it resume. Does it print any message?

Comment: No, the console does not change anymore after it freezed, but the program itself continues running, as I can see it's using CPU/GPU and periodically saving data.

Comment: Then it is not Windows pausing your program, it is the program itself that hangs somehow. You should debug it to determine the cause.

Comment: @satfra: Your program must have high CPU usage ( nearly 100%) , reduce the CPU usage otherwise, if left unattended , OS may assumed that it is non-responsive and may even shut-down.

Comment: @seccpur: The only thing the program does when freezing is going through a loop where it enqueues two kernels, again and again, until it stops every about 100 steps to let the queue finish and writes this to the console. When I run this on my internal GPU, CPU usage is very low, almost 0%, but the issue still happens. It also happens only once, if I "wake it up" it keeps running, but doesnt output a thing to the console anymore. There is not a lot I can debug, sadly, as in this part of the program almost nothing happens within the host program.

Comment: @satfra: Disable screensaver and system power saving modes. If this don't work you have to bring the CPU/GPU usage lower. I usually try inserting sleep(10ms) in loops which are draining the CPU cycles. Some developer use 'hear-beat', do some basic counting in an independent thread to tell that  your system is still responsive.

Comment: Sadly, this did not work. I use fftw for fourier transforms, and sometimes the program decides to stop working while doing the fourier transform, over which I have no control. This seems to also break the data. Can I somehow tell windows to keep my process running at all times?